# nested data only shows up in console.log when I click submit but later once I console.log its gone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a project using react / javascript front end and a rails backend. in my project the models are "users" "setups" "instrument_setups" and "instruments". I am getting access to setups by serializing them through users and then setups can add instruments to itself through "instrument_setups". I finally got it to work successfully where when a user creates a new setup there is also an instrument drop down where you can add any instruments and when I console.log(setups) in the moment that you click submit you can see the nested instruments object, but after the fact if I console log it later you cant see it even though when I look at the backend data as json through the server the data is showing up the way I serialized it. I'm very confused as to why this is happening.

Here's my setups component:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../context/UserContext';

import Setup from './Setup'
import SetupForm from "./SetupForm"

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


function Setups() {
  const { loggedIn, user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [formFlag, setFormFlag] = useState(false);
  


  if (loggedIn) {
    const setupsList = user.setups.map((setup) => {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <Setup key={setup.id} setup={setup}/>          
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Setups </h3>
        {setupsList}
        <br />
        {formFlag ? 
          <SetupForm />
          :
          <Button 
          onClick={() => setFormFlag(true)}
          className='createsetupbutton'
          >Create Setup</Button>
        }
        <br />
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <h3> Not Authorized - Please sign up or login</h3>
    )
  }
  
}

export default Setups;
```

here's my SetupForm component:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../context/UserContext';

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import {
  OutlinedInput,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  FormControl
} from "@mui/material";


const SetupForm = () => {
  const { user, setUser, instruments } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState("");
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");
  const [instrumentIds, setInstrumentIds] = useState([]);

  function updateUserSetups(setup) {
    const updatedSetups = [...user.setups, setup]
    const updatedUser = {...user, setups: updatedSetups}
    setUser(updatedUser)
  }
   
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    fetch(`/setups`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        description: description,
        photo: photo,
        genre: genre,
        instrument_ids: instrumentIds
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('data', data)
      updateUserSetups(data)
    })

  }
  return (
    <Container>
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Label htmlFor="title">Name:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Form.Label htmlFor="description">Description:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        as="textarea"
        rows={3}
        type="text"
        name="description"
        value={description}
        onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Form.Label htmlFor="photo">Photo:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="photo"
        value={photo}
        onChange={(e) => setPhoto(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Form.Label htmlFor="genre">Genre:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="genre"
        value={genre}
        onChange={(e) => setGenre(e.target.value)}
      />
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 500 }}>
        <InputLabel>Instruments</InputLabel>
        <Select
        multiple
        value={instrumentIds}
        onChange={(e) => setInstrumentIds(e.target.value)}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="instruments" />}
        >
        {instruments.map((instrument) => (
          <MenuItem key={instrument.id} value={instrument.id}>
            {instrument.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <br/>
      <Button variant="success" type="submit">
        Add
      </Button>
    </Form>
    </Container>
  );


}

export default SetupForm;
```